# make browser ignore validation on postback which is a "Previous"

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

I'm using client validation

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Customer_Email" name="Email" type="email" required="" />
    <!-- more fields -->
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="prevbutton" Text="Previous" OnClick="prevbutton_Click" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="nextbutton" Text="Next" OnClick="nextbutton_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How can I disable the client side validation if the user click **Previous** but still have it working on **Next**?

*Edit*

I've read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx and added

```
CausesValidation="False"
```

to the button, no change; Chrome still alerts that the field is required.

*Edit 2*

The resulting html is

```
<input name="ctl00$cphContentMiddleRight$Customer_Email" 
id="ctl00_cphContentMiddleRight_Customer_Email" 
class="form-control input-md" 
type="email" required="">

<input type="submit" name="ctl00$cphContentMiddleRight$prevbutton_2" 
value="Previous" id="ctl00_cphContentMiddleRight_prevbutton_2" class="btn btn-default">
```

Nothing I can see that tells the browser not to do its native validation.

Answer (score 1):

Set `CausesValidation` to false on the Button.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="prevbutton" Text="Previous" OnClick="prevbutton_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
```

You can do something like this by adding an `OnClientClick` to the button and remove the attribute

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="prevbutton" Text="Previous" OnClientClick="removeValidation()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function removeValidation() {
        $("#<%= Customer_Email.ClientID %>").removeAttr("required");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Does not work; it is not included in the generated html, so the browser does not see it.

Comment: What is not included in the html? because I can pretty much assure that this work when using aspnet Validators. Adding `required` does not work on all browsers and this is not supported by aspnet. Either switch to aspnet Validators or create your own jQuery form validation functions.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a custom solution. However I still recommend using a `RequiredFieldValidator`.